# Threads not executing in method

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to learn threads by building a web crawler, In the following code
searchHelper(website, keyword); finds all the links from a web page and keeps the links that have a keyword within the url, the idea is that searchHelper is called and then for each link found a thread is formed to act as web crawlers, so for example if the FIRST website contains 5 links on it then 5 threads will be formed so that there will be five web crawlers working together, currently the threads are not working so that i only get the results from the first page, I have been able to get it to work without threads, for example if i remove the entire for loop and replace with the while loop then the web crawler program works as expected, any help would appreciate, here is the method that performs the threads

```
    private void search(String website, String keyword) 
{
    searchHelper(website, keyword);
    int limit = queue.size();
    Thread[] threads = new Thread[limit];
    for(int i = 0; i < limit; i++)
    {
        threads[i] = new Thread(new Runnable() 
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                while(!queue.isEmpty() && queue.size() <= 10000)
                    searchHelper(queue.poll(), keyword);
            }
        });  
        threads[i].start();
    }

    if(results.isEmpty())
        text.append("No results, sorry :(");
    else
    {
        text.append("\nList of results:\n\n");
        for(String x: results)
            text.append(x + "\n");      
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to wrap the while block with a try...catch. In Java threads, if an exception gets thrown without a catch, the thread will silently die. Also, what queue implementation are you using? Java's standard library datastructures are not all thread safe. If they detect being modified on different threads, they start throwing exceptions.

Comment: J-Bar ok thx will try, im using ConCurrentLinkedQueue which i read is thread safe supposedly

Comment: You should look into the `join()` method, you can use that to wait for all the threads to finish.

Comment: No, you don't for more threads. You form tasks and you submit them to an executor service.

Comment: Re, "...and then for each link found a thread is formed."  You should learn about _thread pools_ (e.g., [`java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't wait for the threads to finish. The last part of your code will probably be reached before even a single thread finishes its work, so no results can be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Add this right after your for-loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < limit; i++)
{
    threads[i].join();
}
```

This way your main thread will wait for all of the threads to finish execution before accessing the results.

Comment: Yup that was the problem cant believe i didnt notice that in 2 hours lol